# How to calculate percentage between data from two hashes

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I have two lines of code that output a hash each: One with a count specific for a rating (for example `"super"` or `"good"`) and one with a count for all ratings.

Rating specific:

```
Car.send(rating).group("DATE_TRUNC('week', created_at)").order('date_trunc_week_created_at asc').count
```

Count all:

```
Car.group("DATE_TRUNC('week', created_at)").order('date_trunc_week_created_at asc').count
```

This is the output hash from the first line of code. The second line outputs something similar, just with a higher count, as it counts all ratings, not just one.

```
{2013-03-11 00:00:00 UTC=>21,
 2013-03-18 00:00:00 UTC=>26,
 2013-03-25 00:00:00 UTC=>22,
 2013-04-01 00:00:00 UTC=>38,
 2013-04-08 00:00:00 UTC=>67,
 2013-09-16 00:00:00 UTC=>1}
```

How do I calculate how much percentage the value from hash 1 is against the value of hash 2? I know how to calculate percentage (`value1 * 100 / value2`), but I don't know how to get the values out of the hashes. The date has to stay like it is now. I only have to calculate the percentage of the value.

Edit: As requested, 2 hashes + expected outcome:

Hash 1

```
{2013-03-11 00:00:00 UTC=>21,
2013-03-18 00:00:00 UTC=>26,
2013-03-25 00:00:00 UTC=>22,
2013-04-01 00:00:00 UTC=>38,
2013-04-08 00:00:00 UTC=>67,
2013-09-16 00:00:00 UTC=>1}
```

Hash 2

```
{2013-03-11 00:00:00 UTC=>42,
2013-03-18 00:00:00 UTC=>89,
2013-03-25 00:00:00 UTC=>345,
2013-04-01 00:00:00 UTC=>56,
2013-04-08 00:00:00 UTC=>123,
2013-09-16 00:00:00 UTC=>5}
```

Expected outcome (`value hash 1 * 100 / value hash 2`)

```
{2013-03-11 00:00:00 UTC=>50,
2013-03-18 00:00:00 UTC=>29.213,
2013-03-25 00:00:00 UTC=>6.376,
2013-04-01 00:00:00 UTC=>67.857,
2013-04-08 00:00:00 UTC=>54.471,
2013-09-16 00:00:00 UTC=>20}
```

Comment: The queries are not relevant as far as i can see. Please provide two simple example hashes (hash1 and hash2) and the expected output.

Comment: You seem to have hashes, but the title mentions arrays.

Comment: Sawa, good spot. Mixed up arrays and hashes. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

If both hashes have the same keys I see no problem just doing:

```
h3 = Hash.new()
h1.each_key do |key|
  h3[key] = h1[key]*100.0/h2[key]
end
```